# Rails Multiple CSV Export Buttons Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv

I am looking to add two buttons to the page, each downloading a different CSV file containing different information. However, I'm struggling with routing the controller to the two different downloads.

I had it working with one button downloading one file, but now I added a new parameter to distinguish the two buttons (and link to the two different files to be downloaded) and it is saying "MISSING TEMPLATE".

Here is my controller code:

```
def show
    @shareholder = Shareholder.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.csv do
            if(params[:set] == 1) then
                send_data @shareholder.acquired_csv, filename: @shareholder.name + "-acquired-shares-#{Date.today}.csv" 
            end
            if(params[:set] == 2) then
                send_data @shareholder.summary_csv, filename:  @shareholder.name + "-sold-shares-#{Date.today}.csv" 
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Here is the code for my action items:

```
action_item :acquired_shares_csv, only: :show do
  link_to 'Acquired Shares CSV', shareholder_path( format: :csv, id: params[:id], set: 2 ) 
end

action_item :sold_shares_csv, only: :show do
  link_to 'Sold Shares CSV', shareholder_path( format: :csv, id: params[:id], set: 1 )
end
```

Does anyone know what I could do to have the two buttons?

Comment: add a redirect or render nothing after the send_data so it doesn't try to show a view template for the csv file.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thanks for your reply! I added redirect_to '/admin/shareholders/' + params[:id] after the send_data in order to just redirect back to the users page after downloading the file, but it still gives the error... I'm starting to feel as if it isn't reading params[:set], since if I add a redirect outside of the if statement, it runs that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is in this conditional statement `params[:set] == 1` all parameters are string here.

> it is saying "MISSING TEMPLATE".

```
 format.csv do
    if params[:set] == 1
       # ....
    end
    if params[:set] == 2
       # ....
    end
 end
```

In this case the `params[:set]` is a string and becomes `"1"` or `"2"`, both your conditional statement are skipped and Rails is unable to find template and raises the `MISSING TEMPLATE` error.

Change the code from `params[:set] == 1` to `params[:set] == "1"` or `params[:set].to_i == 1` this should resolve your issue.